# If $\frac{r^2}{AP^2}$ can stated in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $\gcd(a, b) = 1$. Determine the value of $a + 10b.$

Tags: geometry, contest-math

[image]

> Given a circle $ω$ with center $O$ and length of radius $r$. There is
> a point $A$, $B$ on the circle and point $C$ outside the circle so
> that $BC$ tangent to the circle $ω$. Then $AC$ intersects the circle
> $ω$ at $D$. Then $P$ is the midpoint of $AC$ and $AD = BP = BC$. If $\frac{r^2}{AP^2}$ can stated in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $gcd$ $(a, b) = 1$. Determine the value of $a + 10b.$

Suppose $AP = y$, $DP = x$

with the power of point theorem, i get :

$BC^2=CD.AC\Longrightarrow (x+y)^2=2y(y-x)\Longrightarrow x^2+4xy-y^2=0\Longrightarrow y=x(2+\sqrt{5})$

i need an equation containing $x$ and $r$,but I didn't find it, if someone can help, that's great!!!

[There](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VDb6ZeLi-b5ocu995fod4mKDbrdu_zbp/view?usp=sharing) are the original question, Page 4, Number 5.

Comment: I don't know what it means for a line segment to "pertain" to a circle. Does that mean it is *tangent* to the circle?

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for correction, I translate it using google translate

Comment: @user884324: Check to make sure you've stated the problem correctly. By brute-force calculation, I get
$$
\frac{r^2}{AP^2}
=
\frac{1138-432\sqrt{5}}{209}
$$
which is not a rational number.

Comment: @quasi that problum correctly,

Comment: @user884324: Can you give a reference to where the original problem is stated?

Comment: This question is taken from a simulation of district competition in Indonesia, and uses Indonesian Language

Comment: I have put the link above

Comment: @user884324: Then based on the result I gave in my first comment, the contest question is flawed. That sometimes happens.

Answer (score 2):

The ratio ${\large{\frac{r^2}{AP^2}}}$ can be computed by brute force as outlined below.

1. Assume $y=1$.

   Since the ratio ${\large{\frac{r^2}{AP^2}}}$ is scale invariant, we can assume $y=1$.

   Compute $x$.

   By power of a point we get $(x+1)^2=(1-x)(2)$, so
   $$x=\sqrt{5}-2$$

   Compute $\cos\bigl(\angle{BCP}\bigr)$.

   By the law of cosines in triangle $BCP$ we get
   $$\cos\bigl(\angle{BCP}\bigr)=\frac{1}{2(x+1)}$$

   Compute $BD$.

   By the law of cosines in triangle $BCD$ we get
   $$BD=\sqrt{3-7x}$$

   Compute $\cos\bigl(\angle{CBD}\bigr)$.

   By the law of cosines in triangle $CBD$ we get
   $$\cos\bigl(\angle{CBD}\bigr)=\frac{3(1-x)}{2(1+x)\sqrt{3-7x}}$$

   Compute $\cos\bigl(\angle{OBD}\bigr)$.

   Since angles $OBD$ and $CBD$ are complementary we get
   $$
   \cos\bigl(\angle{OBD}\bigr)
   =
   \sin\bigl(\angle{CBD}\bigr)
   =
   \sqrt{1-\cos^2\bigl(\angle{CBD}\bigr)}
   =
   \frac{\sqrt{748-198x}}{44}
   $$

   Compute $r$.

   By the law of cosines in triangle $OBD$ we get
   $$r=\frac{22\sqrt{3-7x}}{\sqrt{748-198x}}$$

   Compute ${\large{\frac{r^2}{AP^2}}}$.

   Since $AP=y=1$ and $x=\sqrt{5}-2$ we get
   $$
   \frac{r^2}{AP^2}
   =
   r^2
   =
   \frac{22(3-7x)}{34-9x}
   =
   \frac{1138-422\sqrt{5}}{209}
   $$

Thus we've computed ${\large{\frac{r^2}{AP^2}}}$, but contrary to the claim of the problem statement, it's not a rational number.